# Mobile number and message text checking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

First of all, m not so good at PHP and learning it, please help.

I want to make a page where I accept only mobile number and text and send it to 'process.php' for process next step after the following check.

A1- Mobile field contain only digits (no alphabet, no '+ or -', no 'comma'). If field contain any non-digit, alert "Only Numeric Values Allowed", delete the mobile field contain and focus on it again.

A2- Mobile field only allow 10 digits (not less than equals to 10 or not more than equals to 10). If field contain less than or more than 10 digits, alert "Only 10 digits Allowed", delete the mobile field contain and focus on it again.

A3- Mobile field's digits start with 7, 8 or 9 (no other starting digits like 0 to 6 allowed). If starting contain 0 to 6, alert "Only 7, 8 or 9 at start allowed", delete the mobile field contain and focus on it again.

A4- If Mobile field remain blank, alert "Please enter mobile number".

B1- Text field check only 160 character (less than 160 allow but more than 160 not allowed) and display real time 'character remain' field below text field.

B2- If text field remain blank, alert "Please enter text massage".

If all the 'A'- section (for mobile field) & 'B'- section (for text massage field) validity check complete then mobile field and text massage field send their data to 'process.php' for process next step.

I have worked on it long but still need more to do and arrange it properly. Please need help and Thank You in advance

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function checkNum(x) {
    if (!(/^\d+\d{9}$/.test(x.value))) {
        alert("Only 10 Digits Numeric Values Allowed");
        x.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
// ]]>
</script>
<script type = "text/javascript" >
// <![CDATA[
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#tm_field").keyup(function () {
        el = $(this);
        if (el.val().length >= 160) {
            el.val(el.val().substr(0, 160));
        } else {
            $("#charNum").text(160 - el.val().length);
        }
    });
});
// ]]>
</script>
</p>
<p>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</p>
<p><strong>This Free SMS page is still under construction,</strong></p>
<p><strong>M working on it &amp; it will start soon ................</strong></p>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><span data-mce-mark="1"><span color="red" style="color: red;" data-mce-mark="1">*</span> Mobile Number </span></td>
                <td>
                    <p><input type="text" name="NUM" id="mn_field" onchange="checkNum(this)" /></p>
                    <p><small> Please enter 10 digits mobile number, only.</small></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span data-mce-mark="1"><span color="red" style="color: red;" data-mce-mark="1">*</span> Text Message </span></td>
                <td align="center"><textarea id="tm_field" rows="7" cols="25"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" align="center">Character remain(s)</td>
                <td id="charNum">160</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Bye Bye SMS" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffffcc" align="center"><small><span style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-mark="1">N.B.</span><strong> </strong>:- A " <span color="red" style="color: red;" data-mce-mark="1">*</span> " indicates a field is required</small></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: While I continue to read this I thought I should point you in an easier direction:  Masked Input jQuery Library http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I would like to recieve a "massage" for sign up into your webpage :D

Comment: [Textbox Accept Only Numbers (Digits) Using Jquery](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/06/textbox-accept-only-numbers-digits.html)

Comment: I'm really curious about requirement A3... Why limit your users to an NPA starting with 7, 8, or 9? That only covers 154 area codes... or 39% of all current area codes, most of which go to US States except for 17 Canadian area codes, 2 for Puerto Rico, and 9 more that cover various Caribbean destinations. Technically speaking, any NPA assigned by the NANPA can start with 2 or higher (as can the NXX).

Comment: [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) m trying to make a page by which any one from the world can send SMS in Indian mobile number (which start with 7,8 or 9 only) (+91 Indian ISD code will added in process.php)

Comment: [Miguel Gonzalez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/802115/miguel-gonzalez) m making this project as sms sending page but thanks for your idea, I had already think about sending a sign up congratulation sms and mobile verification code during member's join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your requirements, I would write the number validation function (A) like this:

```
    var checkMobileNumber = function checkMobileNumber(number) {
            var nonNumeric = /\D+/g,
                indianMobileNumber = /^[7-9]\d{9}$/g,
                allNumeric = false,
                match = false,
                isValid = false,
                message = '',
                error = {
                    "": null,
                    "required": "A mobile number is required.",
                    "invalid": "The mobile number you have entered must start with 7, 8, or 9.",
                    "wrong length": "The mobile number must consist of exactly 10 digits.",
                    "non-numeric": "The mobile number can only consist of numeric values."
                };
        if (number.length !== 10) {
            if (number.length === 0) {
                message = 'required';
            } else {
                message = 'wrong length';
            }
        } else {
            allNumeric = !nonNumeric.test(number);
            match = indianMobileNumber.test(number);
            isValid = allNumeric && match;
            if (!isValid) {
                if (!allNumeric) {
                    message = 'non-numeric';
                } else {
                    message = 'invalid';
                }
            }
        }
        // returning an object containing the overall validity and the error message
        return {
            "isValid": isValid,
            "errorMessage": error[message]
        };
    };
```

and integrate the message validation function on `form.submit` like this:

```
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var errSum = $('.error.summary').empty(),
            num = $('#mobileNumber'),
            sms = $('#smsMessage'),
            smsIsValid = sms.val().trim().length > 0,
            test = checkMobileNumber(num.val()),
            p = $('<p />');
        if (!smsIsValid || !test.isValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (!test.isValid) {
            errSum.append(p.clone().text(test.errorMessage));
            num.get(0).focus();
        }
        if (!smsIsValid) {
            errSum.append(p.clone().text('Please enter a message to send.'))
            if (test.isValid) { // no sense in taking focus away if the mobile number is bad.
                sms.get(0).focus();
            }
        }
        num.siblings('.error').toggleClass('active', test.isValid);
        sms.siblings('.error').toggleClass('active', sms.isValid);
        // normal correct return is below.
        return test.isValid && smsIsValid;
    });
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/

You might note that the working demo "alerts" the user by adding the error message to `div` element instead of calling `alert` (it's a little more polite to your users).

**UPDATE**

For your fiddle, simply make:

```
alert('Wait: SMS Sending...');
return false; // return false to prevent form submission or return true to allow it
```

the last two lines of your `validateForm` handler. Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDcUT/4/

However if you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/, the only thing you would have to do is change the text to "Wait .. SMS sending" at the end of the `form.submit` handler.

You also might note that in my demo, I do not use inline JavaScript handlers and I strictly separate content from presentation and behavior.

This is a good practice to get into (and you can read a multitude of articles on the web about it). A good one to start with is http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: Thank U [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) & m really appreciate your reply & help. But in the mean time m also solve the problem(s) by using trial & error method with various codes, which includes some real time alert but I am highly oblige if U look after my new code and guide me for rearranging or make it more improve (if necessary). I need another 'alert' "Wait .. SMS sending"(in green) if all is OK. [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nDcUT/3/): http://jsfiddle.net/nDcUT/3/. Please reply, m waiting for your guideline

Comment: Thanks for reply [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete). Actually I don't know any programming, m a simple accountant; 3years ago I found that I love coding, from then I start making a site "[ImpossibleWorld](http://impossibleworld.x10.mx/iwsn/)" by self-teaching & collecting code from various sites and persons; wish to lunch it one day. So I don't understand what U mean in 'update's 3rd para' (You also might...and behavior) but I really love to put your entire "alerts" style in my code, e.g. all alert display beside 'Bye Bye SMS' instead of notice appear on screen. Your help need

Comment: [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) I need help, as per your guidance and the articles from http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/ I separate css and js file and try to call it form external link ... everything; like mobile number check and massage check working fine but mobile number and massage are not send to 'process.php'. It also not working in your your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/ too but the my fiddle code which you update in http://jsfiddle.net/nDcUT/4/ working, it send to 'process.php'. Please help me ....WAITING

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: Please post another question. I will be happy to take a look, and you might even attract interest from other users who would be happy to help as well.

Comment: But [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) my previous problem is not solved ...as per your guidance I separate css and js file and try to call it form external link ... everything; like mobile number check and massage check working fine but mobile number and massage are not send to 'process.php'. It also not working in your your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/ too but the my fiddle code which you update in http://jsfiddle.net/nDcUT/4/ working, it send to 'process.php'

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: Your previous problem was not about form submission, it was about displaying the correct error message prior to form submission. **If your previous problem remains unsolved then unmark my solution as the answer.** The form does not get submitted in the demo fiddle I made because I *intentionally* prevent it from happening. Read the comments in the fiddle where it says `normal correct return is below.` Uncomment that line and delete the rest of the lines after it (like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) your present update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/1/ is not working anymore, it submitting the form but not checking the mobile number or the massage's requirement; just only submitting the form. Please help Sir

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/2/ (missed a word). **and** ask a new question about form submission. Give other users a chance to help you.

Comment: I need one last help [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) please, the last update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/2/ do not give "Form would have been submitted" massage (in green). Please update fiddle for last time in such a way that if all checking are OK (3 for mobile number and 1 for massage) then it give "Please wait ... SMS sending" massage (in green) until the page submit to 'process.php'. Please Sir, U help me lots but one last time ... m waiting (Lots of thanks in advance)

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: Of course it doesn't. The point of http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/2/ was to make a fiddle that submitted, not one that pretended to (like http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/). If you want it say something different, change the text.

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: Also, unless you're using AJAX to post the form data to the server, you are **not** going to be able to have a "Please wait" message. The form will post *immediately* to the server and then come back when the server has finished. This process typically blanks the page out until the server returns.

Comment: [Sir Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) isn't there any way by which we can do both (green 'SMS sending' massage and submitting form) at the same time. Give "Please wait ... SMS sending" massage (in green) until the page loading and submit to 'process.php'.

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: Yes, you can use AJAX to submit the form. *Post another question on how to do that* as it is unrelated to this post.

Comment: Thanks [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) for all this help. Can U check http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/ one more time for me, please. If I edit the last line (77th line) of js file form 'return false;' to 'return;' and remove the just above line (76th line) 'e.preventDefault();' totally, then the codes doing all,- like mobile number **only numeric check** -A1, **10 digits check** -A2, **start with 9 8 or 7 check** -A3, **non-blank check** -A4, **non-blank massage box check** -B2 and also submitting the form. I just want to know "What effect it make on codes if I edit this 2 lines?"

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: Changing `return false;` to `return;` is the same as `return undefined` and will not really affect anything. Removing `e.preventDefault();` submits the form, but will not likely show any message as the page is then posting to the server. Removing lines 73 to 78 and changing line 72 to `return test.isValid && smsIsValid;` will submit the form as it should. If you really want to display a message to the user while you are submitting the form, use AJAX to submit the form. If you need help doing that, **please** post another question regarding how to do that.

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: I really don't mind helping you, however it is **completely unfair** to the other users of SO to continue this discussion in the comments here. The point of SO is for programmers to help other programmers, and while you may be "a simple accountant", you are venturing (quickly) into the world of programming so, henceforth, you are also a programmer. Please ask your questions, and we will be happy to help you, **but** ask them individually in different posts. Doing this helps your own reputation and allows the community to build their own reputation while helping you.

Comment: Thanks [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete). Actually from the difference of http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/1/ & http://jsfiddle.net/rawvm/2/ I find out, that the removal of 'false' in last line of js page make the form submit but now I understand changing `return false;` to `return;` is `return undefined` so I use `return false;` to `return true;` and it work fine as well as `return` no more remain undefined. `e.preventDefault();` stopping it's default work -submit, for massage but I really want to display the massage just for only few millisecond until the page posting to the server

Comment: [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) till 28th Nov I read and trial the ideas of SO, on 28th Nov first time I made an a/c and post for help in SO. So I have no idea how the other users of SO be unfair if I continue this discussion in the comments. As I post my problem, U replied and guide me; like that, others also can replied and guide me and build their reputation if they have any ideas. As U guide me from the beginning and well known about my problem so I always point U first but as U see no one replied me other than U also. (May be m wrong as m not know about the SO's system)

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: It's unfair in that other users do not get the chance to post answers to your questions. The community upvotes good answers and downvotes poor answers. Upvotes give users more reputation. Downvotes take away reputation. When you mark an answer as "accepted", it gives you and the person who answered the question more reputation. By having an extended discussion in chat, no one else gets any chance to upvote or downvote. Also, people who use SO to find answers to their own questions do not benefit from extended discussions.

Comment: [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) I understand 'Upvotes' and 'Downvotes' and also 'reputation' on accepted but don't understand how or why other users do not get the chance to post answers to **me questions**, except U ?? Do I have to post same question twice or thrice for getting answers form 2 / 3 users of SO ??

Comment: @Worldofgoutam: No other users are looking at this question because it has been marked as answered. As no other users are looking at it, they won't provide any further insight. Post a new question and others will see it and have the chance to respond. You should post a new one anyway as you have a new problem. I have asked you to so do four times now. Consider this my final plea: **PLEASE, I BEG OF YOU... POST A NEW QUESTION ABOUT HOW TO USE AJAX TO SUBMIT A FORM**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: A good question attracts a lot of interest. You can make your question a good one by asking a clear concise question, showing just the relevant code, and describing where you're stuck.

Comment: [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) U may ask me to post a new question many times but as I have no new subject to ask so I don't want to post old question again and most important is that I have no idea about 'No other users are looking at this question because it has been marked as answered' else I will not marked it as answered until I get clear and complete idea about my problem ....

Comment: I don't know any other ways to put this. You do have a new subject to ask about. **The specific subject is "How can I use AJAX to submit a form?"** Ask the question. I'm sure you will find an answer. **This is my last comment on this post. Any further comments you leave on this post will go unanswered by me.**

Comment: [Pete](http://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) I don't need to ask "How can I use AJAX to submit a form?" because what I wanted to know was already answered (guided) by U. In last 2/3 of my post, I just try to tell U that as m new in SO (not new, first time put post), so I have no idea about all this **'Upvotes'** , **'Downvotes'** , **'Reputation on Accepted or Answered'** and specially **'Marked as Answered Question are not reply or guide anymore'** type of system of SO until U clearly explain me. So please don't misunderstood me and also don't get mad on me. + THANKS for everything.